# NTP peer does not syncronize

Tags: ntp

i set one ntp server . but ,peer does not synchronize time from server. i set accurate time on my client site .but when i want to synchronize time from server by typing this command  "ntpdate -u server.cse.local" ,then it goes to previous state. and previous time was wrong .here is log file

client log file: -
29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3176]: ntpd exiting on signal 15

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: Listen normally on 3 ens33 192.168.0.101 UDP 123

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: Listen normally on 4 ens33 192.168.0.102 UDP 123

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: Listen normally on 5 virbr0 192.168.122.1 UDP 123

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: Listen normally on 6 lo ::1 UDP 123

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: Listen normally on 7 ens33 fe80::f5f7:60c:d942:138 UDP 123
29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: Listening on routing socket on fd #24 for interface updates
29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: 0.0.0.0 c012 02 freq_set kernel 0.000 PPM

29 Aug 13:32:10 ntpd[3469]: 0.0.0.0 c011 01 freq_not_set

29 Aug 13:35:24 ntpd[3469]: 0.0.0.0 c614 04 freq_mode

what can i do now ???

Comment: Is this a VMware virtual machine?

Comment: yes.  i am working on vmware 15

Comment: You need to synchronize the clock on the host, first.

Comment: how can i do it ???  you say that, at first i use my ntp server on my windows machine ? which is my physical machine